# ArCore Camera not found: 0

Tags: android, kotlin, arcore

i am facing problem in ArCore. I am trzing to run activity with fragment, but app crashes with this log :

```
E/native: status.cc:156 generic::not_found: Camera not found: 0
```

D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

```
--------- beginning of crash
```

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.goodrequest.matel, PID: 3055
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.goodrequest.matel/ui.ArCoreActivity}: com.google.ar.core.exceptions.FatalException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3429)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3469)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732)

```
                            ...
```

calling activity :

```
main_button_launch_ar.setOnClickListener {
       val intent = Intent(this,ArCoreActivity::class.java)
       startActivity(intent)
   }
```

My activity :
class ArCoreActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_arcore)

}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.ar" android:required="true" />



<application
        android:name="ui.Applicatiooon"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">


    <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.ar.core"
            android:value="required" />

    <activity
            android:name="ui.MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
            android:name="ui.ArCoreActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

what am i doing wrong guys ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out this is not problem in code, but problem in emulator